# Interactive drop down menu that auto fills drop down values depending on what user inputs

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create an interactive drop down menu that uses mysqli query to autofill the values in each drop down. So far the first drop down menu echo's the Brands in the database for each part so that works fine. However the second drop down displays regardless of the $selected value being true or false, but also when I do select a brand it doesn't auto fill the results.

```
    <?php
            foreach($parts as $col) { ?>
                <dl>
                    <dt><?php echo $col?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <select id="search_status" name="state" data-placeholder="State">
                            <?php
                           $brand = $database->fetch_col($col);
                           $selected = false;
                           ?>
                               <option value=""></option>
                            <?php foreach($brand as $b){ ?>
                               <option value="<?php $selected = true; ?>"><?php echo $b['Brand']; ?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
                        <?php if($selected = true){
                            $item = $database->fetch_row($col, $b);
                            ?>
                        <select>
                            <option></option>.
                                   <?php foreach($item as $i) {?>
                                   <option><?php echo $i['Model']; ?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        } else {
                            echo "Please select Brand";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <p><?php
                        echo var_dump($item);
                        ?><p>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            <?php }?>
```

I'm fairly certain its the $selected variable not corresponding with the rest of the form.

Comment: Consider creating a PHP endpoint for the SQL db info you need and using JS to hit the endpoint and handle the interactivity on the front-end with your form.

Comment: `<?php $selected = true; ?>` Did you mean `<?php $selected == true; ?>`

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response! It did sort of solve my problem, however now the drop downs that has an option changes the $selected value to true. On the Bright side it now displays "Please select Brand" on a drop down that has no Brands in it. So Progress!!! @RiggsFolly

Comment: Actually that `<?php $selected = true; ?>` does not seem to make much sense in that piece of code

Comment: It was the only thing i could think of xD Still new to coding. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Remember, you cannot know what to place in the second dropdown until you have let the user select something in the first dropdown. SO you will have to wait till they submit the form, look at what was selected in the first dropdown and then fill the seconds dropdown accordingly

Comment: Alternatively you will have to learn some javascript and fill the second dropdown dynamically using AJAX

Comment: Okay thank you i'll look into it @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the $selected to true by using a single equal sign - if you want to compare the value to true you need to use == or ===.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: It might be a good idea to show the OP WHERE in their code they are doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to do it.Here i share some example.YOu can find your solution from it...
Main page:

```
  <html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

AJax Page 
ajax.php

```
    <?php 
echo "ss";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">


<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a> 
<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a> 
<a href="signup.php">Sign up</a> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you.